# Is it safe to keep sensitive data in branches that are not pushed?

Tags: git, security, privacy

Suppoe I am working in `git` and I make a branch called `sensitive` and commit sensitive data (e.g. passwords, keys) in `sensitive`.  I never commit sensitive data in `master`, and I never merge `sensitive` into `master`, but I do pull `master` into `sensitive`.  When I `git push origin master`, is there any danger that I will push blobs of sensitive data to the server?

Comment: If you never commit sensitive data, and never name a branch or tag or whatever something that is sensitive, then a `git push` won't push sensitive data. However, the onus is on you, the developer/user of git, to ensure you never commit sensitive data. See the top answer here for a better way that has more safeguards and is the "typical" way people decide to handle this situation.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is about Git but, in fact, your problem is a different one. And it has (at least) one solution.

1. Put the sensitive data in a file named, let's say, `config` and add it's name (and path) to `.gitignore`.
2. Create a duplicate of this file, let's name it, `config.dist`, replace the sensitive data with dummy data and add it to the repository (it must never contain sensitive data). Explain in the header of the file that it must be copied as `config` and customized.
3. Let the code load its configuration from `config`. For bonus points, you can let it load `config.dist` if `config` is not available.
4. Commit and push.

The file `config.dist` works as a template for the actual `config` file that is never stored in the repo. Each developer can customize their `config` file as they need/want. Let `config`/`config.dist` contain all the information that change from one system to another or might change during the lifetime of the project (file paths, database connection parameters, passwords etc.)

---

To answer your question, the solution presented above is 100% safe (let apart the human errors). Since the `config` file never reaches the repo, no matter how Git works internally, the sensitive data will never be pushed to a remote repo.

Comment: And git hooks (e.g. pre-commit) could be implemented to protect it even further from human errors.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no danger. If you do not consider the sharing of sensitive data to all the people that can access to you repository.